# Getting segmentation fault while access address of variable, but can access the value of variable

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I tried to assign pointer a value from other variable directly without giving it an address.
It seems that the pointer now have an address and value but the variable that i used to assign has a value but address out of reach, because i can get the value of that variable but getting segmentation fault while trying to get its address. Here is the code :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int x = 1;
    int *y;
    *y = x;
    printf("y address : %x\n", y);
    printf("y value : %d\n", *y);
    printf("x address  : %x", &x); // causing segmentation fault
    printf("x value : %d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

> segmentation fault

But if i try without that line :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int x = 1;
    int *y;
    *y = x;
    printf("y address : %x\n", y);
    printf("y value : %d\n", *y);
    // printf("x address  : %x", &x); // causing segmentation fault
    printf("x value : %d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

output :

> y address : d701c7b0
> y value : 1
> x value : 1

Comment: `int *y;  *y = x;` Where is `y` pointing? Somewhere random, maybe?

Comment: yes, that is what i'm not able to understand. The address of y and where does the address of x went ? Somewhere random ? But we can still access its value though.

Comment: Look up "undefined behavior"... The SEGFAULT may take a moment to be processed before the OS kills off your executable. That's why you're seeing something... just before being terminated. Don't deliberately write bad code. The challenge of programming is to write **good** code, and that is hard enough...

Comment: No, MridulThakur, @Fe203 is guiding you to what your problem is.

Comment: yes, but i don't think that it is right to call it "undefined behavior" and let it go. There should be some logic going on there. Maybe it is corrupting the memory addresses of os or anything like that.
Well, i may be sounding a bit stupid cuz i am new to this language

Comment: It **is** right to call it _undefined behavior_ because the consequences are **undefined**. Anything could happen! The sun could rise in the west! Dorothy could travel to Oz. "Undefined" means undefined and "anything" means anything.

Comment: I think i understood it. Isn't it a vulnerability then ? Maybe we can use it for exploits or anything like that. btw thanks. I thought that i am lacking somewhere before but now as it is "undefined behavior", i'll let it go.

Comment: Would you close your eyes and drive, at speed, through the city on a busy afternoon? (Can't believe I'm quoting from a Clint Eastwood movie...) "Feeling lucky, punk?" `:)`

Comment: nope i won't, btw i also don't have any driving license. Just joking, i understood your point, but then what should i do ?

Comment: There are two possibilities.  The best one is what you are experiencing - your app attempts to write, through the unassigned pointer, to some location that your OS has not assigned write access privilege.  The memory-management hardware will not allow the execution of the write and, instead, raise some kind of structured exception that usually ends up killing your process.  The worse possibility is that the  write through the pointer is allowed because it happens to write to some writeable data in your process,  so causing some undesired malfunction that is difficult to debug:(

Comment: One more point. My very ancient C compiler **warms** `local [pointer] variable 'p' used without having been initialized`... I'd trust Dennis Ritchie to ignore that warning, no-one else, not even myself... As @martin james wrote, you may be {un]lucky and a hard-to-find bug may live in your code, eating into your free time hours... Strive for good code...

Answer (score 0):

The pointer `y` needs to point to something if you want to dereference it.  I introduced a variable `int x2` initially set to a different value so you see the assignment through a pointer working.  Also changed the first format string to use a %p instead of %x and added new lines to the format strings that were missing them:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int x = 1;
    int x2 = 42;
    int *y = &x2;
    *y = x;
    printf("y address : %p\n", y);
    printf("y value : %d\n", *y);
    printf("x address  : %p\n", &x); // causing segmentation fault
    printf("x value : %d\n", x);
}
```

and the output:

```
y address : 0x7ffdfce5b9f0
y value : 1
x address  : 0x7ffdfce5b9f4
x value : 1
```